# How does Heroku allow only my git account to push to its created git remotes?

Tags: git, heroku

I wonder how Heroku handles the security of git remotes.
When I try to make a new app and deploy it from my local environment,
I use the command

```
Heroku create
```

Then, after it created a Heroku git repository, I create a remote from it.

```
git remote add Heroku 'repository remote link'
```

Does it mean that anyone can take this remote link and push to the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Heroku guide (like this one) start with [`heroku login`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started).

That means an [`heroku create`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote) is done within that session, and makes you the owner of the remote repository.

You need [`heroku access:add`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collaborating) commands to add collaborators before they can push to your remote repository.

Comment: you mean that 'Heroku login' allow any git to push to the remote during Heroku session?